# Batch file to download a file from FTP

Tags: windows, ftp, batch-file

i want to download the "abcd.txt" file 'n' times with step of 2 mins.
Following is the batch (with ftp script in it) file i've created to download a file from FTP.

```
:DOWNLOAD_AGAIN
@ftp -i -s:"%~f0"&GOTO:DOWNLOAD_AGAIN
open 192.168.4.4
username
password
!:--- FTP commands below here ---
cd /data/
pwd
get abcd.txt
bye
```

The problem is, 
1) Above batch file does not wait for 2 mins, it immediately starts downloading the file again.
2) I dont know how to restrict it to download only 'n' times.

Any help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

PING can be used to delay execution for a number of seconds.
If specified (-w switch), PING will wait for a number of milliseconds between two pings before giving a time-out.

i.e. PING 127.0.0.1 -n 6  for a 5 seconds delay.
or 
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 60000 >NUL
will delay execution of the next command 60 seconds, provided 1.1.1.1 is not a valid IP address

Also 
you can use
TIMEOUT 120
will delay execution of the next command by 120 seconds

And for running batch for n times 
you can do

```
FOR /L %i IN (1,1,n) DO (
       //to stuff
 )
```

The 1,1,n is decoded as:

(start,step,end)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Kaushal's answer, if you're on Vista/7, you may use

```
TIMEOUT /T 120 /NOBREAK
```

instead of `ping` to have the script pause for 2 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Grab [Unix Utilities port](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/), there is a useful `sleep` program there, which will allow you to delay the script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CHOICE`'s timeout to wait:

```
CHOICE /C XY /D X /T 120 > NUL
```

(offer a prompt choice of X or Y, default to X in 120 seconds & return, hide choice by directing to nul)